# Join on a 2 Column Struct in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I want to join a flat table onto table with a struct in big query but the table needs to join on 2 columns in the struct. Is there a way to do this? Below is example data and what I've tried.

```
prices_table

| row | id1       | id2       | price  |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------ |
| 1   | 0000001   | a         |  12000 |
| 2   | 0000001   | c         |  15000 |
| 3   | 0000002   | c         |   2000 |
| 4   | 0000004   | a         |   5000 |
```

```
array_table

| item    | array.id1 | array.id2 |
| ------- | --------- | --------- |
| apple   | 0000001   | a         |
|         | 0000002   | b         |
|         | 0000003   | c         |
| pear    | 0000004   | a         |
|         | 0000005   | b         |
|         | 0000006   | c         |
```

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
SELECT p.*, a.item
FROM prices_table p
LEFT JOIN array_table a
  ON id1 IN UNNEST(array.id1)
  AND id2 IN UNNEST(array.id2)
```

But it causes incorrect joins

```
expected

| row | id1       | id2       | price  | item  |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 0000001   | a         |  12000 | apple |
| 2   | 0000001   | c         |  15000 | null  |
| 3   | 0000002   | c         |   2000 | null  |
| 4   | 0000004   | a         |   5000 | pear  |
```

```
actual

| row | id1       | id2       | price  | item  |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 0000001   | a         |  12000 | apple |
| 2   | 0000001   | c         |  15000 | apple | < incorrect
| 3   | 0000002   | c         |   2000 | apple | < incorrect
| 4   | 0000004   | a         |   5000 | pear  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with offset` to align the arrays after unnesting them:

```
SELECT p.*, a.item
FROM prices_table p LEFT JOIN
     (array_table a CROSS JOIN
      unnest(a.id1) i1 with offset as n1 JOIN
      unnest(a.id2) i2 with offset as n2
      ON n1 = n2
     )
     ON p.id1 = i1 AND p.id2 = i2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach

```
select * from prices_table p
left join (select item, id1, id2, from array_table a, a.array)
using(id1, id2)
```

if to apply to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: did you have chance to try?